# Boot problem after installing 15.04

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I have attempted to install Ubuntu 15.04 on a Dell Inspiron 5720 but when i reboot i just get a black screen with some flickering text which appears to say some abount not being to open ...efi files. It flickers to fast to read for sure.
I do not want windows 8 which was installed, just ubuntu.

I have tried boot-repair but that didnt work even using advanced options
http://paste.ubuntu.com/12596200/

I have tried re-installing many times but the result is the same and i am getting very frustrated with it now.

MartynT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a lot of useless NVRAM entries, as revealed by the `efibootmgr` output in your Boot Repair output. I don't think that's the real problem, but you might try removing them, thus:

```
sudo efibootmgr -b 0001 -B
```

Repeat that for `000E`, `000F`, `0010`, `0011`, `0012`, `0013`, and `0014`, in addition to `0001`. When you've done this, reboot. I doubt if it will fix anything, but it might.

Next, enter your firmware setup utility and, if you enabled it, disable your CSM (aka legacy boot mode support). This feature, although sometimes useful, complicates the boot path and can create problems. If your computer is trying to boot in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode, it's probably reading the GRUB you've got in your MBR, which is failing because, as Boot Repair says:

```
 => Grub2 (v1.99-2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 
    1060428 of the same hard drive for core.img, but core.img can not be found 
    at this location.
```

In other words, the BIOS-mode GRUB is only partly installed. Your EFI-mode GRUB seems better, and is configured to launch first if the computer is booting in EFI mode; however, it's possible that there's something wrong with it.

If you still can't boot at this point, I recommend you download the USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) Prepare a boot medium from that and boot from it. It should enable you to boot Ubuntu. There will probably be two entries, one of which boots GRUB (which I expect will fail if the preceding procedures don't help) and one of which boots a Linux kernel directly (which I expect should boot). If you can boot via the external rEFInd medium, you can try installing it to your hard disk via the PPA or Debian package; or you can try to manually debug GRUB.